# What is faster Rails 4: find_or_create_by vs. validates uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a large amount of CSV importing to do and the file gets split into four models with relations to each other. The question for import speed is this:

Is it faster to use this kind of code:

```
model1 = Model1.find_or_create_by(accountNumber: .....) do |x|
## add fields
end

model2 = Model2.find_or_create_by(randomAttributenr2: xxx) do |x|
...
end
```

or to just say

```
model1 = Model1.new(....)
```

and then to validate the uniqueness in the model?

Conceivably, the second method should be faster as it involves only 1 db call that either goes through or fails vs the first method that does 2 calls, 1 to check and 1 to create.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you the complete second method is the following:

```
model1 = Model1.new(attrs)
model1.valid?
```

If that is the case, you really are not saving much as `valid?` does the same exact thing as the "find" in `find_or_create_by` (runs a select statement on the table with the `by` attribute in the where clause).  The only really difference is `valid?` will return a boolean where `find_or_create_by` returns the queried object.

Comment: i would not use valid but rather validates uniqueness: true in the model file. Would that save time?

Comment: Does the same thing.  ActiveRecord checks uniqueness by running a `SELECT` on the table with the unique field and new value passed into the `WHERE` clause.  You can see this by attempting to create records in your rails console.